# Ajax jquery issue when I receive data from the server

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get back a reply from a web server. To do that, I use an ajax script to send a request and get back a json or xml data.
The web server is Indy. I don't know this kind of server and haven't any possibility to modify the configuration.

I've done two js script.
The 1st sends a request to a web server Django. After modifying the configuration to allow CROS request, the client side gets back correctly the data from the server.
The 2nd sends a request to the Indy web server. After modifying the ajax request (datatype = "script"), I get back a reply but that soons empty.

The differences between the 2 replies that I found come from the header of the reply.
From the Indy web server, I get:

> Content-Disposition :"inline; filename="toto.dat""
>   Content-Type :"application/octet-stream"

At the opposite, from Django it's

> Content-Type :"application/json".

Here is my code

```
    $("#button1").click(function(){
    alert("Script 1");

    // Script to request on Django web server

     $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:80/polls/getid",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (xhr, status, response) {
            alert("coucou");
            var resp = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
            alert(resp.id);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});


$("#button2").click(function(){
    alert("Script 2");

    // Script to Indy web server

     $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/index_xml?callback=?",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "script",
        success: function (xhr, status, response) {
            alert(response);
            var resp = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
            alert(resp.id);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

These are the headers:

Header reply script 1

> HTTP/1.0 200 OK
>   Date: Thu, 26 Nov 2015 13:40:00 GMT
>   Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.9
>   access-control-allow-origin: *
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Header reply script 2

> HTTP/1.1 200 200 OK
>   Connection: close
>   Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>   Content-Length: 92
>   Content-Disposition: inline; filename="job00ZT6VI8NQO9O09479E0E1B.dat"
>   Server: Indy/9.0.18

Have you an idea about how to deal in js script the Indy reply. I guess I receive a file instead of some data. But I'm quite lost.

Comment: It will help if you post some of your code

Comment: You can explain with thousand of paragraphs, but we understand better the code than the word explanation. share your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

)

I've found a solution.
First time I read about JSONP, I haven't really understood what about. So I've tried several things without success.

I've read again about JSONP and finally understood that when ajax sends a query with a callback value, the server has to use this attribute as a function to reply to the client.

Example:

> AJAX side:

```
http://...?callback=jQuery111109043251063544318_1448672067019
```

> Server side reply:

`jQuery111109043251063544318_1448672067019({"id":"1234"});`

@ViRuSTriNiTy  Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#button1").click(function(){
    alert("Script 1");

    // Script to request on Django web server

     $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:80/polls/getid",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (xhr, status, response) {
            alert("coucou");
            var resp = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
            alert(resp.id);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});


$("#button2").click(function(){
    alert("Script 2");

    // Script to Indy web server

     $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/index_xml?callback=?",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "script",
        success: function (xhr, status, response) {
            alert(response);
            var resp = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
            alert(resp.id);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What the heck is this? An answer, an edit of your question or what?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you set `dataType: "script"` instead of `dataType: "text"` when you try to access `response.responseText` in `success()`? Makes no sense, so change `dataType` to `text`, it should work.

You could also try to use the [converters](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#using-converters) setting.

Comment: Because if I change from script to another kind of data, I get a CROS error on the client side. And I haven't any possibility to modify the server configuration.

Comment: @HansB Ok, my answer now states an additional approach by using converters, hope this works.

Comment: Ok I will have a look on the converter. But one thing I don't understand is if I add a breakpoint at the line alert(response), in the Firefox debugger, there is nothing in the xhr or response object.

Comment: Is there any way to see data that the client has received ?

Comment: @HansB Yes, use Fiddler, a tool to monitor HTTP traffic.